# Adding an echo with a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have an echo = "000000" and a string named $id which is an integer.

If $id is = 1, how do I add "000000" + $id to get 000001 ?

Comment: apparently someone forgot what it was like to be new at something....

Answer (score 7):

You could check out [str_pad](http://php.net/str_pad)

In your case it would be something like:

```
str_pad('1', 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function padWithZeros($s, $n) {
  return sprintf("%0" . $n . "d", $s);
}
```

Where $n is the number of zeros you want, e.g:

```
echo padWithZeros("1", 6);
```

That pads the number 1 with five zeros to equal six places

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%06d", $id)
```

Answer (score 1):

$temp = "00000".$id;
echo "ID = $temp";

Answer (score 1):

str_pad is the PHP function that does exactly what you want.  However, printf is a well understood method of doing that that works across most common languages.  It probably makes sense to use printf in this case to make the code more readable.